# Is there a windows IRC client that supports embedding media

Tags: windows, irc

I'm trying to get my team to use an In house IRC client.  They want inline pictures.  I haven't found a client that supports this yet, and I haven't found a way to add this feature to any client that I've found.  I've found a couple browser based clients, but this is no good because we don't want our private data to potentially go out of our network

This question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/262118/is-there-an-irc-client-for-ubuntu-with-inline-media) has an answer like what I want but, as far as I can tell, that's only for linux.

Does anyone know of a client, or plugin for a client, to support embedding media?

Comment: On that page, Pidgin is a good possible candidate. It is a rather non-conventional IRC client, but it can be used as an IRC client.

Comment: I looked at pidgin, but I didn't find anything that would support it showing pictures in windows.  I looked at the links from that page, but, unless I didn't understand, they don't work for me

Comment: @Darius looks like this Pidgin plugin is not yet available for windows -- https://code.google.com/p/pidgin-embeddedvideo/

Comment: I tried to hack this into the open source flow (https://github.com/bretternst/Floe) but I never got very far.  now we're using slack which is still a less than ideal situation.